# In if-else statement throwing this error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, passwords

I was trying to build a password generator in Python with this code:

```
import random
import string

print("Welcome to password generator !")

def password_generator():


    lowercase_data = string.ascii_lowercase

    uppercase_data = string.ascii_uppercase
    numbers = string.digits
    symbols = string.punctuation

    combined = lowercase_data+uppercase_data+numbers+symbols

    lenght= int(input("Enter your password lenght:"))

    if  lenght == None:
        print("please enter your value")
        password_generator()

    else:


        generator = random.sample(combined,lenght)

        password = "".join(generator)

        print(password)
        password_generator()


password_generator()
```

When my input is blank it shows this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Now what should I do with this code??

If my input is blank then I want to continue with the if-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    lenght = int(input("Enter your password lenght:"))
except ValueError:
    lenght = None

if  lenght is None:
    ...
```

Trying to convert a non number value to an int generates a ValueError - as you've seen. If that happens, set `lenght` to None, and carry on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch an exception here. You try to parse a string to int by using `int(...)` on a string that can literally contain anything.

In your case, it is empty, so it cannot parse anything to an integer. Your `if length == None` afterwards is rather useless, because `int()` will not return `None` but instead throw an error (see the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)).

You need to catch this error one way or the other, either by surrounding the statement with a try except block or by sanitizing the input (i.e. taking `a = input("Enter your pw length:")` and then checking if it only contains digits before you call `int(a)`